# Floating two columns of text to the right of an image?

Tags: html

I am a bit stuck on this one.

I am looking to float two vertical columns of text next to an image.
I know how to float text to the right or left of an image, but unforunately I do not know how to float two columns?

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add your html code to the question.

Comment: Example http://jsfiddle.net/y5wp17w9/1/

Comment: Cheers Justin, Is there anyway to do this by using just the html code and not css?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><img style="width:100px;" align="left" src="http://recruitmentbuzz.co.uk/recruitment/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/google-zip.jpg"/> Row 1<br/><br/>Row2</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7sw60bmy/

Comment: yeah, I need two columns?